# Can I create a reverse ssh tunnel by using my Android phone as the middle man? 

Tags: windows, ssh, android, nat, tunnel

I am trying to connect my home linux laptop and my work Windows 7 computer.  They are both behind NAT w/ firewall and neither allows port forwarding.  I cannot control the NAT, firewall or port forwarding.

Ideally I would like the linux box to be the server and the Windows machine to be the client, however to make a SSH tunnel, I need a third party.  The only third party that I have at my disposal would be my cell phone.

It is an Android with 4G access and unlimited data.  Is it possible to use the cell phone as the third party/middleman?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20040923.html

Comment: Is there a way to do that on my android phone?